# Please add search option strings into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, localization, international-sites, transifex

Currently we, SOja users, cannot translate strings for search options. Is it possible to translate them?

Screenshots:

- Related to https://ja.traducir.win/strings/3509

  > [image]
  >
  > https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aquestion
- Related to https://ja.traducir.win/strings/11204

  > [image]
  >
  > https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bada%5D+is%3Aquestion

Comment: To close voters: Note, that Transifex is used for the localization of several communities.

Comment: I've done a search and can confirm that those strings are not in transifex. We can't translate them in [es.so] neither.